# In vue-imask how do I get the IMask class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate, imaskjs

My question is very similar to this one for angular: [In angular-imask how do I get the IMask class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71772195/in-angular-imask-how-do-i-get-the-imask-class)
I'm especially interested about the Vue Composition API https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/vue-imask#mask-composable-vue-3 to be able to call `mask.updateValue()` in order to make it work with VeeValidate (ex: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/value-formatting).

Here is the message I get from the console:

> Element value was changed outside of mask. Syncronize mask using `mask.updateValue()` to work properly.

I've tried to retrieve the IMask class like that `const { mask } = useIMask(formatterMask)` but it is not the IMask class unfortunatly.

Any idea how to proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IMask` instance is indeed [stored in `mask`](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/blob/d34f6f3/packages/vue-imask/src/composable.js#L48) returned from `useIMask()`. Since `mask` is a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), you need to unwrap it via its `.value` property:

```js
const { mask } = useIMask(formatterMask)

console.log(mask.value) // => IMask instance
```

Comment: Thank you, I can now access it. The point now is I get an error by calling `mask.value.update()` saying the object read-only and cannot be modified (https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/blob/d34f6f3/packages/vue-imask/src/composable.js#L93) 
Any idea how to get around that issue without forking the library?